# Activemq - Why Not Delete The File When BlobMessage Has Been Consumed?

Tags: blob, activemq-classic

I produce a BlobMessage to broker, then the binary file would be saved in the
fileserver(inside jetty).
However, even when I consumed that BlobMessage and get the binary file, the
file saved in the fileserver still exists!! Named 
:ID_MyConputer-3581-1189147531234-0_0_1_1_1. 
Why not delete it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which method you use to create the BlobMessage,
if you use `ActiveMQSession.createBlobMessage(URL url);` message will not be removed by the broker, you need to set `message.setDeletedByBroker(true);` on the message.

> deletedByBroker indicates whether or not the resource is deleted by
>   the broker when the message is acknowledged

or you can explicitely delete it by calling `ActiveMQBlobMessage.deleteFile()`